# SQL Server TABLOCKX not locking the table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

I have a big table with millions of records and I try to use `TABLOCKX`, I must update some data in exclusive.

I test this transaction

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

SELECT * 
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable] WITH (TABLOCKX) 
WHERE 0 = 1

WAITFOR DELAY '00:30'

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

If I try to select the data in this way

```
SELECT *  
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable]
```

There is no LOCK on the table I can READ the data.

But I discovered that if I try to select from table in this another way the lock it WORKS!

```
SELECT *  
FROM [MyDatabase].[dbo].[MyTable] WITH (TABLOCKX)
```

Why? I tried to create another table test with 3 o 4 record and the lock works fine without "WITH (TABLOCKX)".

Comment: Hello,

I think the problem is in the WHERE condition as 0=1 is always FALSE.

Comment: @DanielE. I tried now, but it not working... :(

Comment: Why don't you set the `isolation level to serializable`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-transaction-isolation-level-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: What is happening to make you think the lock is working/ not working?   Also are you using 2008 or 2016?   Why tag both?

Comment: @TabAlleman I tag both because I Tested this on 2008 and 2016 and both have the same weird behavior. The lock works only on the query with "WITH (TABLOCKX)" without I can read uncommitted data.

Comment: what's your default isolation level? read committed? snapshot isolation?